# How to upload file from Laravel Public directory to google drive in

Tags: laravel, google-drive-api

When I upload it in HTML form it works fine. but when I want to upload files from the Laravel public directory it's not working.
My code in Controller:

```
function createFile($file, $parent_id = null)
    {
        
        $file = FileStorage::find($file)->first()->UniqueFileName;
        $name = gettype($file) === 'object' ? $file->getClientOriginalName() : $file;
        $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
            'name' => $name,
            'parent' => $parent_id ? $parent_id : 'root'
        ]);
        $content = gettype($file) === 'object' ?  File::get($file) : Storage::get($file);
        $mimeType = gettype($file) === 'object' ? File::mimeType($file) : Storage::mimeType($file);
        $file = $this->drive->files->create($fileMetadata, [
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => $mimeType,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'
        ]);
        dd($file->id);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, "but when I want to upload files from the Laravel public directory it's not working" <<<=== define "it's not working". Put a try/catch block around your call to Google drive, catch the exception

Comment: @UnderDog It's just creating a file with the given name but when I open it it's showing: couldn't preview the file the file is empty.

Comment: there's something wrong with $content

Comment: @DaImTo but as I mentioned up that it's working fine when I upload from HTML form

Comment: Er go there is an issue with how you are getting the file source when not uploading from the HTML form.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your "laravel public directory" you need to upload the contents of the file.   I normally use.  $content = file_get_contents('../files/photo.jpg');   I question what  Storage::get is returning both data wise and data type.    You may also want to check what mime type Storage::mimeType($file); is returning because if thats wrong its not going to be able to open the file either.